# Find duplicates and replace it on new arrays with the same index position

Tags: javascript, arrays, duplicates, type-conversion, reduce

I need to find the same elements by key value "groupName", and make a group of them on the same index position in the new array, and if groupName is null just leave it in the same position

For example:

```
const list = [
    {
        id: 1,
        groupName: null
    },

    {
        id: 2,
        groupName: 'group_1'
    },

    {
        id: 3,
        groupName: 'group_1'
    },

    {
        id: 4,
        groupName: 'group_2'
    },

    {
        id: 5,
        groupName: 'group_2'
    },

    {
        id: 6,
        groupName: null
    },
    ...
];
```

Expecting something like that:

```
const newList = [
    {    
        id: 1,
        groupName: null
    },

    [
        {
            id: 2,
            groupName: 'group_1'
        },

        {
            id: 3,
            groupName: 'group_1'
        }
    ],

    [
        {
            id: 4,
            groupName: 'group_2'
        },

        {
            id: 5,
            groupName: 'group_2'
        }
    ],

    {
        id: 6,
        groupName: null
    },
];
```

I tried to use reduce for that, but can't save the same index position in newList
What is the best way to do something like that?

Comment: I think you should group the item even the groupName is null for the consistent data structure.

Comment: What if the input is not sorted by group?

Comment: What do you mean with "same index position"? For example, the object with `{ id: 4, groupName: 'group_2' }` is in `list[3]` and in `newList[2][0]`; the index is not the same in the two arrays.

Comment: @secan Yes, I got your point. It's should looks like in the example, guess it's more informative. I mean the equal objects should wrapped in new array while during the loop. But of course, the index will be different, thanks for the notice.

Comment: @ikhvjs yeah I think you're absolutely right. But its should be in one loop list ... and position is important ... maybe I need to create a different structure but in one scope ..

Answer (score 0):

[EDIT] According to your last comment, if you want to group also objects whose `groupName` is `null`, you simply have to modify the code I posted before with

```js
const list = [
  { id: 1, groupName: null },
  { id: 2, groupName: 'group_1' },
  { id: 3, groupName: 'group_1' },
  { id: 4, groupName: 'group_2' },
  { id: 5, groupName: 'group_2' },
  { id: 6, groupName: null },
];

const newList = list.reduce((acc, item) => {
  const arr = acc.find(_item => Array.isArray(_item) && _item[0].groupName === item.groupName);
  arr ? arr.push(item) : acc.push([item]);
  return acc
}, []);

// test
console.log(newList);
```

[ORIGINAL] I am not 100% sure I understand your requirements but, given your `list` input array, you can obtain the `newList` output one with:

```js
const list = [
  { id: 1, groupName: null },
  { id: 2, groupName: 'group_1' },
  { id: 3, groupName: 'group_1' },
  { id: 4, groupName: 'group_2' },
  { id: 5, groupName: 'group_2' },
  { id: 6, groupName: null },
];

const newList = list.reduce((acc, item) => {
  if (!item.groupName) {
    acc.push(item);
  } else {
    const arr = acc.find(_item => Array.isArray(_item) && _item[0].groupName === item.groupName);
    arr ? arr.push(item) : acc.push([item]);
  }
  
  return acc
}, []);

// test
console.log(newList);
```

In a nutshell:

1. you check if the current item has a falsy `groupName` and, if it has, you push it into the output array
2. otherwise you check whether there is already a sub-array for the item `groupName` and, if you find it you push the item into the existing sub-array, otherwise you push into the output array a new sub-array containing the item

Comment: Thanks a lot, that is exactly what I'm looking for. Your [ORIGINAL] version is the answer. It looks heavy but that is the solution, you really help me. Once again thank you.